# R: Extracting json data from an OData API gives inconsistent results?

Tags: r, json, odata, jsonlite

I'm attempting to extract data from the Wales government statistics services OData API. Details on the API can be found [here](https://statswales.gov.wales/Help/Catalogue#APIEndpointsExplained), including an example of how to filter the data.

However I seem to be getting a non-deterministic subset of the data i.e. each attempt results in a different number of records returned.

Below is a simple reproducible example.

Additionally I have also tried:

- using `RJSONIO::fromJSON()`, which has the same result.
- attempting to use the `odata.nextLink` url, if it is returned in the json object, to keep extracting more data. Again, each attempt results in a different sized object.

Any insight will be much appreciated.

```
## preliminaries
library(jsonlite)

# prepare filters
filter1 <- "Column_ItemName_ENG"
filter1.value <- "Gross%20expenditure"
filter2 <- "Row_ItemName_ENG"
filter2.value <- "Parking%20of%20vehicles"

query <- paste0("http://open.statswales.gov.wales/en-gb/dataset/lgfs0009?$filter=",
                filter1, "%20eq%20%27", filter1.value, "%27%20and%20",
                filter2, "%20eq%20%27", filter2.value, "%27")

# test 1
test1 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(query)
test1 <- test1[[2]]

# test 2
test2 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(query)
test2 <- test2[[2]]

# test 3
test3 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(query)
test3 <- test3[[2]]

# compare results
nrow(test1)
nrow(test2)
nrow(test3)
```

PS: this question is cross-posted from [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/extracting-json-data-from-an-odata-api-gives-inconsistent-results/26705), and I promise to update either post with relevant solutions found on the other one.